# Removing directory recursively

Tags: batch-file, directory, subdirectory, shared-directory, delete-directory

I'm doing a single Batch-File currently that deletes all contents from a specific folder on the Server.
It is working so far, but directories with spaces in the Folder name will not be recognized unfortunately.
I have no idea where to put the quotation marks in the script to overcome this limitation.

This is the script so far, it sits in the root of "D:\" :

```
cd Sharedfolder
for /f %%i in ('dir D:\Sharedfolder /B /D') do rd %%i /Q /S
del /F /S /Q *.*
```

It works good, but as soon as I have a Directory inside of "Sharedfolder" it will not work for that directory.

Answer (score 6):

There is a mismatch in the command use. either use **for /f** or use

```
FOR /D %%i IN (D:\Sharedfolder\*) DO rd /s /q "%%i"
del /F /S /Q *.*
```

Which is closer to what you were thinking. An alternative solution would be to:

```
rmdir /s /q D:\Sharedfolder
mkdir D:\Sharedfolder
```

Tough this may have some problems elsewhere in the system.

Answer (score 1):

This is the complete answer you are looking for, Try this one:

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /b /ad abc*') do rd /s /q "%%x"
```

I have tried, It works.

Comment: No it does unfortunately not work.
It tries to delete "D:\Sharedfolder\D:\Sharedfolder" and its subdirectories.
Also, i had to place the "%%I" before the /S /Q to make it do anything at all.

Comment: I have edited the answer, and also checked the solution. Its work fine. All the best.